# Add gif image on placeholder of imageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gif

I have loading.gif image.

My Coding is:-

```
[cell.Vehicleimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[DetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"resim1"]]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.gif"]];
```

My problem is that, i want to add gif image on placehoder of UIImageView. But animation is not working.

can anybody help me.

Comment: In iOS, .gif files are not supported, So you can use library for it

Comment: Ok, now i can change the gif image to 4 static image. And i think if i show one by one fastly, then it will be show like animation,..Can you please provide the Coding for that..

Comment: Ok, wait I will post my code

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: OR U can use https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Comment: https://github.com/mattt/AnimatedGIFImageSerialization

Comment: https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: I have check your given url , but in all the image view can download and animated gif image, but my issue is that i want to set the gif image on placeholder until the image can not loaded in imageview.

Comment: I told you just set this [UIImage imageNamed:[arrslidingimages objectAtIndex:index]]; as your placeholder image and when your image is downloaded set [NSTimer Invalidate];

Comment: but how can i check my image is downloaded or not..

Comment: You cAn use block of sd_image like [img_userimage sd_setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
            if (!error) {
                img_userimage.image=image;
            }
        }];

Comment: so when your image is downloaded img_userimage.image=image; this will set your image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131333/discussion-between-jecky-and-hari-mohan).

Comment: I want to use this code,
[YeddiEminImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"image"]]]  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) { if (!error) {
            
            YeddiEminImg.image = image;
            [t invalidate];
}
        }];
But where i use this code, if i use in changeimage method than how can placeholder image will be work..

Comment: you can directly instead set gif image to your imageview and from this method you can check your image is downloaded and stop timer for gif

Comment: This method also save cache of your image which prevent downloading everytime. It downloaded once and saved in cache for further use

Comment: Ok, Enjoy then.

Comment: You can contact me anytime , If i free sure will help you

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, .gif files are **not supported**. You have to go for workaround.

One option is to split image and run the animation to change images which makes it looks like gif animation.

For that **One option**:

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

You can load more than one gif images.

You can split your gif using the following [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) command:

```
convert +adjoin loading.gif out%d.gif
```

**Second option:**

Use third party library like below:

[FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)

**Third option**

Implement using WebView like this:

```
extension UIView{
func animateWithGIF(name name: String){
    let htmlString: String =    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head>" +
                                    "<body style=\"background-color: transparent;\">" +
                                        "<img src=\""+name+"\" align=\"middle\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%;\">" +
                                    "</body>" +
                                "</html>"

    let path: NSString = NSBundle .mainBundle().bundlePath;
    let baseURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String); // to load images just specifying its name without full path

    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
    let gifView = UIWebView(frame: frame)

    gifView.opaque = false // The drawing system composites the view normally with other content.
    gifView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    gifView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)

    var s: [UIView] = self.subviews 
    for i in 0..<s.count {
        if s[i].isKindOfClass(UIWebView) { s[i].removeFromSuperview() }
    }

    self.addSubview(gifView)
}

func animateWithGIF(url url: String){
    self.animateWithGIF(name: url)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use CATransition for it like and set NSTimer for it 
here

```
    CATransition  *slideTransition = [CATransition animation];
    slideTransition.duration = 1.0;
    slideTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    slideTransition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    slideTransition.delegate = self;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage:)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

arrslidingimages is my ARRAY of Images like

`arrslidingimages=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01.png",@"02.png",@"03.png",@"04.png",@"05.png", nil];`

```
-(void)changeImage:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //change timer of the sling image and set the current page of page controller
    slideTransition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight; // or kCATransitionFromRight
    [_Slidingimageview.layer addAnimation:slideTransition forKey:nil];
    index++;
    if(index==[arrslidingimages count]){
        index=0;
    }

    _Slidingimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrslidingimages objectAtIndex:index]];
        // If for any reason you need to cancel the image rotation

}
```

JUST set your placeholder image as

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[arrslidingimages objectAtIndex:index]];
```

IT will give this type of [IMAGE EFFECT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0)

**Hope It helps.Thank you

Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

**Works with swift 3 & 4:**

If you are using SDWebImage , then the best solution would be to use APNGImageSerialization from this [link](https://github.com/rickytan/APNGImageSerialization). Add an APNG image to your bundle and use it like :

```
posterImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:hdposter), placeholderImage: UIImage.animatedImageNamed("placeholderAnimated"))
```

It will show the animated image until the real image is loaded.